# Need session key from facebook to get user data

Tags: java, authorization, facebook

I have an external web app, which needs to connect to Facebook and get user data like contacts, etc. I have successfully setup Facebook connect on my website. now i need to know how I can get a Facebook session key and then get data calling Facebook's Rest Java API. Is there a clear tutorial that does just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this article from [NetTuts](http://www.tutsplus.com) to be really good:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/authenticating-users-with-facebook-connect-and-google-friend-connect/

Comment: It does not really explain how to get the session key needed to make api calls...